# Memory leak(ish?) when using re and mmap

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, mmap

I'm having an "issue" with running a regex search across a big (30-ish GB) `mmap`ped file in python 3.4 (64-bit Windows).

Basically, what I'm observing is that *between* matches hitting, the memory footprint climbs up to roughly the number of bytes between matches. It's not actually crashing, but the footprint is big enough to slow other processes down (because of the size of the mmapped file).

My regex is from a bytes string, it's pretty specific and all quantifiers are bounded. There are no `*` or `+` in my expression, so it's not the case of a hideously overrunning regex (worst case scenario the match will be 2200 bytes long, most hits are smaller). I'm storing the matched string in a list, but there're at most usually only a couple of thousand hits, so it's not the hits which are taking up all that room.

What I'm currently assuming is that the regex engine (sre right?) keeps all of the string between matches in memory, which for small data sets is fine, but for mine it's not really. So my question really is: is this assumption correct and if so, can I alter this behavior (without recompiling the libraries preferably!)

The code is basically this:

```
pattern = re.compile(b"PATTERN.{1,20}", re.DOTALL)
f = open("file.bin", "rb")
mem = mmap.map(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)

results = []
for match in pattern.finditer(mem):
    results.append(match.group(0))

f.close()
```

Comment: it's hard to say. microsoft likes to abuse caching so probably a part of file is cached in the memory by windows.

Comment: I'm not sure this is Windows' fault (or not entirely Windows' fault). The behavior whereby the memory footprint drops every time there's a match feels like it's coming from within the library... I need to run this test on a unix-flavoured box...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a way around this. You are reading a large amount of data as fast as the disk can provide it. Unless you have a stupendous amount of RAM. If you don't at some point you're going to run out of RAM have to free some up. Most OSes will use a LRU (Least recently used) algorithm to decide what to kick out of RAM. Since you're accessing the data as fast as you possible can, most of memory used by the memory-mapped file is going to have recent-ish access times. Thus meaning they are "poor" candidates to be kicked out of RAM (at least according to the OS).

Basically, the OS is making a poor choice about what to kick out of RAM when it runs out of free memory.

However, you know better about what memory can be release. Thus you could scan the file in chunks. This will explicitly let the OS when you no longer need earlier parts of the file, and allow the freeing up of that memory. Of course this creates problems at the boundary of the chunks.

As an example of what you could do to improve the memory performance of your program:

```
import re
import mmap
import os

filename = "some_file.txt"
file_size = os.stat(filename).st_size
chunk_size = 2**32
# chunk_size = 50 # smaller chunk_size I used for testing
regex = re.compile(rb"PATTERN\d{1,20}\n")
max_length = len("PATTERN") + 20 + len("\n")

matches = []
f = open(filename, "rb")    
for i in range(0, file_size, chunk_size - max_length + 1):
    # compute length of data to search over
    length = chunk_size if i + chunk_size <= file_size else file_size - i 

    m = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), length=length, offset=i, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    # f.seek(i) # used for testing
    # m = f.read(length)

    for match in regex.finditer(m):
        if not (match.end() == len(m) and len(match.group()) < max_length and length == chunk_size):
            # if match ends at end of string
            # and not maximum length of regex
            # but not also at the end of the file
            # THEN there *may* be a cross chunk-boundary match
            # THUS, defer match to next loop iteration
            matches.append(match.group())
    m.close()
f.close()
```